# I am not able to login in lamp server after installation is completed properly

Tags: lamp, phpmyadmin

Firstly I have installed Lamp server , then installed phpmyadmin perfectly , then after I have created login with root user and started using it , but after some days I am not able to login with root user.

Second I have created new user login and try to use it but not able to login.

Can you please advise why I am not able to login into lamp server?

Answer (score 0):

Try falling back to using your /etc/mysql/debian.cnf file to access your database subsystem.

Try this command...

mysql --defaults-extra-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf -e "SHOW DATABASES"

If this command fails, then you'll have to reset your database root password, using...

sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-$your-install-version

If the above command works, then somehow your phpMyAdmin password has been munged. To reset your phpMyAdmin password, try...

sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin

If all else fails, you can just destroy all database packages, via...

sudo apt-get purge $packages

Then start again. Although, purging all packages is usually overkill.